# GPS not delivering any serial data

Tags: serialization, raspberry-pi, gps

I connected a NEO-7M-0-000 GPS module to my Raspberry Pi and wanted to check if there is any serial data coming in with

```
sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0
```

But it doesn't show any data. I'm pretty sure the wiring is correct and the LED is lighting up, so I can't figure out the problem. Btw I am using the Raspberry Pi 3B.

I would be glad about any help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the speed (in bps) that the GPS outputs at?

Comment: It supports 9600 bps

Comment: Cool. OP might need to use `stty` to set speed of port to match.

Comment: Do you have `gpsd` running? Please check by calling `systemctl status gpsd.service`.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that D-Sel pin is set to "1". In order to get data over UART protocol you need to set D-SEL to 1. 
[image]

Comment: And how do I set it to low? It says (left open), but I can't really figure out what that means. I connected TX to RX and RX to TX, VCC to 3.3 V and GND to GND. What do I have to change?

Comment: Dont connect D_SEL Can be configured in three ways as below
1) D_SEL  --  High(3.3 / 1.8 V) based on the supply configurations.
2) D_SEL  --  GND 
3) D_SEL --  Neither connected to SUPPLY nor GND(Called Left Open).
Configurations 1 & 3 would configure the pins 20,21,19,18 in UART.
Configuration 2 would configure the pins 20,21,19,18 in SPI mode.